# Оценки идущие в диплом. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с предметами:

```
CREATE TABLE public.predm
(
    -- Полное название предмета
    maxname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    -- Короткое название предмета
    minname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    -- Шифр предмета
    shifr text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    -- Год учебной программы
    gpr_go integer NOT NULL,
    -- Семестр
    sem_per integer NOT NULL,
    -- Категория (Курсовой проект, зачет без оценки, зачет с оценкой, экзамен)
    kateg integer NOT NULL,
    -- Специальность
    spec integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT predm_pkey PRIMARY KEY (maxname, gpr_go, sem_per, kateg)
)
```

Таблица с оценками учащихся:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ocenki
(
    predm text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    gg integer NOT NULL,
    sp integer NOT NULL,
    -- Оценка
    oc integer NOT NULL,
    -- ID учащегося
    id integer NOT NULL,
    kateg integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT oc_pc PRIMARY KEY (kateg, predm, gg, sp, id)
)
```

Приходится сначала искать максимальную категорию (КП, ЗБО, ЗСО, Экз) для конкретного предмета (получается таблица со столбиками: Предмет, Категория) и добавлять в структуру

```
select maxname, max(predm.kateg) from public.ocenki, predm  where ocenki.predm = minname and  predm.kateg=ocenki.kateg and id =  " + ln_list[comboBox5.SelectedIndex] + @" and sem_per = sp group by maxname
```

Потом потом собираю запрос по кусочка:

```
 если(к_во_предметов > 0)
 {
      q="(запрос для первого предмета в списке)";
      for(int i = 0 ; i < к-во_предметов; i++)
           q+="union (запрос для i-того предмета в списке);
 }
```

Усть ли какие нибудь более простые способы вывести что надо?

Comment: Уточните для начала постановку задачи, что именно должно идти в итог. У меня в приложении к диплому курсовые проекты - полностью отдельные записи. зачет или экзамен плюс отдельно оценка за курсовой по тому же самому предмету. То есть для законченного мной вуза ваш алгоритм ошибочен.

Comment: То что красным должен получить. Курсач отдельным запросом. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyCk8.gif

Comment: Т.е. если по предмету сдавались и экзамены  и зачеты, то выводим последний экзамен. Если были только зачеты, то последний зачет.